# Перевод валюты с помощью динамического программирования

Tags: алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Есть вот такая задачка.

Квадратная таблица A размера n × n заполнена неотрицательными действительными числами. Число aij определяет курс обмена валюты i на валюту j. Так, например, если aij = 2,5, то это значит, что за 1 единицу валюты i дают 2,5 единицы валюты j. Если aij = 0, то считаем, что курс обмена валюты i на валюту j прямо не установлен. Необходимо определить, можно ли, имея некоторую сумму денег в одной из валют, получить бо́льшую сумму денег в той же валюте, совершив несколько обменов.

Вот мой код

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {

                double perevod = A[i][j];
                double zamena = perevod * A[j][i];
                if (A[j][i] * A[i][j] > 1)
                {
                    fout << "yes";
                    return 0;
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    if (k != j)
                    {
                        if(zamena*A[j][k]*A[i][k]>1)
                        {
                            fout << "yes";
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

То есть я просто пытаюсь сделать обмен,чтобы у меня получилось в результате преобразований число большое 1. Но не могу корректно доказать,что это будет работать. На моих тестах работает,а контрпримера я не вижу. Может быть кто-то увидит подвох?

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку - эта таблица - представление графа с весами ребер, соответствующими обменному курсу. 0 - ребра нет.

Логарифмируем веса ребер и меняем знак на обратный, после чего просто применяем один из алгоритмов, которые проверяют, нет ли [в графе цикла с отрицательным весом](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/negative_cycle). Если есть - значит - пора бежать в обменник :)

Не уверен, но вот такая матрица -

```
1  1  0  0
0  1  1  0
0  0  1  1
2  0  0  1
```

Она вроде бы дает обмен 0->1->2->3->0, но ваш код его не ловит?